# Is there a specific "rule" about when to use fread() and fscanf_s()?

Tags: c, function, file, text-files, binaryfiles

I have to read data from text files and binary files (in different programs). In different examples, `fscanf_s` is used, and in others `fread` is used. Is one used for binary files while the other is used for text files, or there isn't really a rule?

I am using Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: They're two completely different tools, though I'd argue `scanf` type functions are a crutch at best and are usually better avoided. You can do trivial parsing like that with a simple state machine if necessary, or a parsing library if that's insufficient.

Comment: `fscanf` would be more for interpreting text where `fread` just reads bytes.  `fread` for binary or text files.

Comment: tadman's suggestion is the way.  `scanf` family is the root of half of the questions on here. Also, generally I would avoid the `_s` functions as well.  Just use `fscanf` if you really want it.

Comment: [**Field Experience With Annex K — Bounds Checking Interfaces**](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#impementations): "Microsoft Visual Studio implements an early version of the APIs. However, the implementation is incomplete and conforms neither to C11 nor to the original TR 24731-1. ...  As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable."

Comment: fread is typically *more useful* for binary files and fscanf is more useful for text files. Nothing stops you mixing and matching how you like, but that's how it usually works out.

Comment: If you want to read a certain number of arbitrary bytes, not necessarily ordered into lines, not necessarily even human-readable, often one or more bit-for-bit binary data structures: use `fread`.  If you want to read lines of text: use `fgets`.  And if you want to read free-form, whitespace-separated, human-readable representations of integers, floating-point numbers, spaceless strings, and maybe individual characters, and if you want to spend the rest of your days fighting with extra characters which did or didn't get read, and might or might not need "flushing": use `fscanf`.

Comment: (And don't try to use `fscanf_s`; it's a waste of time.  There might be a place for `gets_s`.)

Comment: ... invented by Microsoft in an attempt to avoid continuing embarrassment over vulnerabilities in Windows arising from sloppy programming.  Their overall effort to write better code seems to have been effective, but I don't give any credit for that to the introduction or use of the `_s` functions.